# How to return the value from the observable and assign it to a variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

i want to return a value from this method from an observable in order to use it in another function by assigning it to the viewcount variable.
how do i properly return the value from the observable and assign it to a public variable for later use in this case.

```
public viewcount:any  

public getcount(id){
  let view = " ";
  this.backandService.getViews(id).subscribe(
    (data:any) =>{
      view = data["0"].views
      console.log(view)
    }
  );
  return view;
}
```

now in the other method i do

```
 public updateViews(id){
     let  view:any = this.viewcount;
       this.backandService.update('videos',id,
  {"viewcount":JSON.stringify(view)}).subscribe(
         data =>{
           console.log (data);
         }
       );
     }
```

but the value is never returned in order to use it in the `updateView` method and in the console log the `updateView` `xhr requests` show  only a 404 not found for it also the `request payload` in the Headers show an empty bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are assigning the value to a module level variable, you can't make that variable a number, but it itself needs to be a promise.

```
public viewCount: Promise<number>;

public requestCount(id){
  this.viewCount = new Promise<number>((resolve,reject) => {
    this.backandService.getViews(id).subscribe(
      (data:any) =>{
        let view = data["0"].views;
        console.log(view);
        resolve(view);
    });
   });
}

public async updateViews(id): Promise<void>{
  let view = await this.viewcount;
  this.backandService.update('videos',id { 
    "viewcount":JSON.stringify(view)}).subscribe(data =>{
       console.log (data);
     });
  });
}
```

The non-async approach:

```
public updateViews(id): Promise<void>{
  return this.viewcount.then(view => ( 
    this.backandService.update('videos',id { 
      "viewcount":JSON.stringify(view)}).subscribe(data =>{
         console.log (data);
       });
    });
  })'
}
```

Comment: If this is Angular 1 (as the question implies), the promise should be wrapped with $q.resolve().

Comment: i tried to use the answer you gave me but i'm getting and error with the `updateViews` method. "async function are only available when targeting ECMAscript 2015 or higher". i''m using ionic 2 framework

Comment: @estus no it's angular2.0 with ionic 2

Comment: @ObedLorisson See Update,

Comment: _Because you are assigning the value to a module level variable, you can't make that variable a number, but it itself needs to be a promise._ is a completely false statement

Comment: @AluanHaddad besides polling, how else would you guarantee that the call has instantiated the value, before attempting to access it?

Comment: I am not objecting to your solution, although you could use `.toPromise` instead of `subscribe` to simplify. I am objecting to your statement: _"Because you are assigning the value to a module level variable, you can't make that variable a number, but it itself needs to be a promise."_ this is erroneous, makes no sense, and is not related to the question.